# Old cartoon TV show (on DVD) about soccer ball-shaped characters that live in outer space or on an alien planet

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, space

It's a TV show where the characters are in the shape of a soccer ball and they live in outer space or on a planet where everyone is also a soccer ball.

They basically have all these fun episodes that mostly involve them playing soccer or something similar and there's commentators who commentate on some of the characters, just while they do daily tasks.

It's a cartoon show and the title was something along the lines of 'Astroballers' or something involving them being in space and a soccer ball.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, was the animation in 2D or 3D?

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if this could be *[The Likeaballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Likeaballs)*, a cartoon series shown on Children's BBC in 2006.

It deals with a race of football shaped aliens - the Likeaballs - who are completely obsessed with football. They all have names that end in -ball, such as Kickaball, Invicniball, and Knowledgaball, and their exploits are commented on by two sportscasters, Dan and Pam.

Quoting [Toonhound](http://www.toonhound.com/likeaballs.htm):

> This approachaball series focuses on the exploits of Team Likeaball,
> an odd    assortment of ball-shaped aliens who are just mad about the
> Beautiful Game.    Seriously, they'll play football anywhere, against
> anyone or thing. Hence a    stream of mis-shaped and mismatched teams
> take up the challenge. Their    opponents include plundering pirates,
> a bounty-hunting robot, a ruthless    virus, even a giant's fingers!
>
> But their most fearful opposition comes in the form of The
> Dislikeaballs.    These folks are the mirror image of our heroes, a
> most disreputaball bag    of balls who are determined to deflate the
> efforts of our heroes at every    turn. Fortunately for everyone, they
> can only ever puncture their own plans.    You see, they just don't
> have that all-important team spirit.

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[Spheriks](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478956/)*** (2002)...?

Hard to find much info about this 3D-animated show, but it was apparently based on the former official mascots of the 2002 FIFA World Cup, and involved a football-like sport called 'Atmosball,' played in a stadium on an alien world. The aliens aren't strictly soccer ball-shaped, but they're relatively short and stout. The games do have commentators, like in real world football.

From [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:The_Spheriks):

> Ato, Kaz, and Nik : Orange, purple, and blue (respectively) futuristic, computer-generated creatures. Collectively members of a team of Atmosball (a fictional football-like sport), Ato is the coach while Kaz and Nik are players. The three individual names were selected from shortlists by users on the Internet and at McDonald's outlets in the host countries.